# Get value from txtfile and put it in arrays

Tags: java, arrays, io

i am trying to read and write files.

i have two txt files

input.txt:

```
   4
   1 1
   2 2
   3 2
   3 3
   2 3
```

and in output.txt i want to get  value from inputx.txt like a

```
    4 //is first value
int[] x = {1,2,3,3,2}
int[] y = {1,2,2,3,3}
```

How to parse it?

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a sample code, its not the best way, but just to give you a hint on how to do it.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        String filename = "text.txt";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        String s;
        int i = 0;
        int firstVal = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer>x=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer>y=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            s=sc.next();
            if( s.trim().isEmpty() )
                continue;
            if( i<1 ){
                firstVal = Integer.valueOf(s).intValue();
            }else{
                if(i%2 > 0 ){
                    x.add(Integer.valueOf(s));
                }else{
                    y.add(Integer.valueOf(s));
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        for(int xv: x){
            System.out.println(xv);
        }
        System.out.println("-----------------");
        for(int yv: y){
            System.out.println(yv);
        }
    }
}
```